# Is there any way to embed a website in <IFrame>, If it is denying to be embedded?

Tags: php, html, iframe

I want to embed 'www.youtube.com' for example in IFrame Tag of HTML, but as you know it won't allow me to embed it. Is there any way or an alternative way for this action?

Comment: Check you don't have X-Frame options set to SAMEORIGIN on your webserver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have to check for the `HTTP` response header X-Frame-Option of those sites.

If its value is

- Deny --> You cannot load the website in IFrame (even if the domain page is the same).
- Sameorigin --> Only a page which is in same domain can load this website in IFrame.

I don't know how deep you've tried it, but otherwise you can try the following example:

You can add YouTube videos to your website by using the `iframe` HTML tags.

1. Use the youtube site to find the video you want
2. Click the 'Share' button below the video
3. Click the 'Embed' button next to the link they show you
4. Copy the iframe code given and paste it into the html of your web page.

Although YouTube gives you `html code` using the iframe tag, you can also include your video using the object tag, its up to you. Here is a small example:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/..."
                width="500" height="300" 
                frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```